# How is the default `search` value in /etc/resolv.conf defined if there is no local domain name?

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, networkmanager, resolv.conf

I am running Kali Linux 2020.4 in VirtualBox 6.1. The image runs in its own NAT Network (created in VirtualBox via *Settings* - *Network*) with DHCP support enabled.

When I run `cat /etc/resolv.conf` I get the following response:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search uni-konstanz.de
nameserver 192.xxx.xxx.x
```

The `nameserver` is the local IP address of my router so I guess VirtualBox uses the default DNS of my router which makes sense somehow. What striked me as odd though is the default `search` value -- this is the domain of my (former) university. I honestly have no idea how it made its way into the Kali Linux image running inside VirtualBox.

In the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf) for resolv.conf it says that "the search list is normally determined from the local domain name", but when I run `domainname` the response is `(none)`.

So my question really is, how does Kali Linux or rather the NetworkManager tool determine its default `search` value in the absence of a local domain name?

When I open the NetworkManager GUI in Kali Linux the IPv4 method is set to "DHCP", so I guess somehow this is information "leaking" from the host OS. The only thing I can think of is that I used to have a VPN service to connect to my university network via Cisco AnyConnect, but that's really all there is.

Everything works fine as is, but I'm still puzzled. Does anyone have a clue? Or is this maybe more of a VirtualBox issue rather than Kali Linux?

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when you distribution is getting its IP information via the DHCP client. The DHCP client will get the search domain from the DHCP server, and append it to resolv.conf.